# how to write the java script for checked check boxes which is in item template of radcombobox

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Actually in my radcombobox i am taking one template in that template i am taking three controls checkbox and linkbutton and imagebutton.i am binding the usernnames to linkbutton. and through itemcommand event of radcombobox i am displaying status in place of image every thing is working fine but my problem is when i check the check box of two users out of five users in combobox while closing radcombobox i want the names of the selected users in combobox by separated with coma(,) is it possible
below is my code

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rdPhysicianscmb" runat="server" Width="75%"
     DataSourceID="sdsAttachedUsers"  Filter="Contains" Font-Size="14pt"
     onitemdatabound="rdPhysicianscmb_ItemDataBound" 
     OnClientDropDownClosed="HandleClose" LoadingMessage="Loading..." 
     EmptyMessage="All Providers">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" Width="10px" runat="server"/>
          <asp:Image Visible="false" ID="ImgAway" runat="server" 
               ImageUrl='images/imgAway.png' Style="height: 25px; width: 25px;"/>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lblphyname" runat="server"  CommandName="Selected" 
               ForeColor="#0489B5" Font-Size="11pt"
               CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AssignedTo") %>'  onclick="lblphyname_Click" 
               Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' Font-Underline="false" 
                Font-Overline="false">
          </asp:LinkButton>      
      </ItemTemplate>
 </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

.ASPX

```
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlEducationPeriod" runat="server" EmptyMessage="--Select education period--"
        HighlightTemplatedItems="true" SkinID="DropDownList194*200" AllowCustomText="true">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" onClick="EducationHeaderCheckChanged();" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTeacherSelectAll" Text="Select All" AssociatedControlID="chkSelectAll"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div onclick="StopPropagation(event)">
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkddlID" onclick="onCheckBoxClickEducation(this)"
                    Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="labelddlID" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

.ASPX.CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic data = new[] {
          new { ID = 1, Name ="aaa"},
          new { ID = 2, Name = "bbb"},
          new { ID = 3, Name = "ccc"},
          new { ID = 4, Name = "ddd"},
          new { ID = 5, Name ="eee"},
          new { ID = 6, Name ="aaa"},
          new { ID = 7, Name = "bbb"},
          new { ID = 8, Name = "ccc"},
          new { ID = 9, Name = "ddd"},
          new { ID = 10, Name ="eee"}
        };

        ddlEducationPeriod.DataSource = data;
        ddlEducationPeriod.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlEducationPeriod.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddlEducationPeriod.DataBind();
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
            function onCheckBoxClickEducation(chk) {

            var combo = $find("<%= ddlEducationPeriod.ClientID %>");

            //prevent second combo from closing
            cancelDropDownClosing = true;
            //holds the text of all checked items
            var text = "";
            //holds the values of all checked items
            var values = "";
            //get the collection of all items
            var items = combo.get_items();
            //enumerate all items
            for (var i = 0; i < items.get_count(); i++) {
                var item = items.getItem(i);
                //get the checkbox element of the current item
                var chk1 = $get(combo.get_id() + "_i" + i + "_chkddlID");
                if (chk1.checked) {
                    text += item.get_text() + ", ";
                    values += item.get_value() + ",";
                }
            }
            //remove the last comma from the string


            text = removeLastComma(text);
            values = removeLastComma(values);


            if (text.length > 0) {
                //set the text of the combobox
                combo.set_text(text);
                //update the treeview in the second combobox
            }
            else {
                //all checkboxes are unchecked
                //so reset the controls
                combo.set_text("");
            }
        }

        function StopPropagation(e) {
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }

        function EducationHeaderCheckChanged() {
            var headerchk = document.getElementById('ddlEducationPeriod_Header_chkSelectAll');
            onCheckBoxClickSelectAll(headerchk.checked, "ddlEducationPeriod");
        }
        function onCheckBoxClickSelectAll(headerchk, combo) {
            var combo = $find("<%= ddlEducationPeriod.ClientID %>");

            cancelDropDownClosing = true;
            //holds the text of all checked items
            var text = "";
            //holds the values of all checked items
            var values = "";
            //get the collection of all items

            //enumerate all items

            var items = combo.get_items();

            for (var i = 0; i < items.get_count(); i++) {
                var item = items.getItem(i);
                //get the checkbox element of the current item
                var chk1 = $get(combo.get_id() + "_i" + i + "_chkddlID");
                chk1.checked = headerchk;
                if (chk1.checked) {
                    text += item.get_text() + ", ";
                    values += item.get_value() + ",";
                }
            }
            //remove the last comma from the string
            text = removeLastComma(text);
            values = removeLastComma(values);

            if (text.length > 0) {
                //set the text of the combobox
                combo.set_text(text);

            }
            else {
                //all checkboxes are unchecked
                //so reset the controls 
                combo.set_text("");
            }
        }
        function removeLastComma(str) {

            return str.slice(0, -2);
        }
```